# Console failing to take input

Tags: c

I am trying executing a c program in which if i enter floating value to an integer variable ,it skips the decimal part as expected but after that it doesnot reads value from console .In the following code snippet , it skips that scanf line if we enter any floating point value.I am unable to find the reason .Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50

void push(int i);
int pop(void);

int *tos, *p1, stack[SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    int value;
    tos = stack; /* tos points to the top of stack */
    p1 = stack; /* initialize p1 */

    do
    {
        printf("\n Enter value: \n");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        printf("\n value entered is %d",value);

        if(value!=0)
            push(value);

        else
            printf("value on top is %d\n", pop());

    } while(value!=-1);

    return 0;
}


void push(int i)
{
    p1++;

    if(p1==(tos+SIZE))
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    *p1 = i;
}


int pop(void)
{
    if(p1==tos)
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    p1--;

    return *(p1+1);
}
```

While entering a floating point value from console it neglects the decimal part and after that do while keeps on executing but it scanf statement doesn't works so after executing it until stack fills , then it exits .Please help to find why scanf doesnot works here ?

Comment: Check your `scanf()` return values. It will return the number of *successful* parses.

Comment: Removed C++ tag, as the code is pure C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask `scanf` to read an integer value. If you then enter e.g. a floating point value, then `scanf` will read the first number and halt at the "point". Then next time you try to read input it will see the "point" and not read anything.

You should check the return value of `scanf`, it returns the number of successfully read and converted items, so for the first call it returns `1` but on all other calls it returns `0`.

You might solve this by reading the whole line into a buffer (using `fgets`), and use e.g. `sscanf` on the buffer. But you should still check the return value to know if the user entered a valid integer or not.